# Show url of a subfolder as a subdomain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, subdomain

Hope someone can help. I'm looking for a way to show the url of a website folder like a subdomain.

Let's say that I have a website www.example.com and a subfolder www.example.com/sub. Is it possible to show the url like www.sub.example.com instead of www.example.com/sub using htaccess' url rewrite, without moving the resources of the sub folder to a "real" subdomain? In other words, is it possible to change only the address of the sub folder?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the hosting control panel by creating the subdomain, which may be the cleaner method...

You can see a similar thread here: [.htaccess Subdomain Redirection](http://web.archive.org/web/20160305065226/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563001/htaccess-subdomain-redirection) (archive.org mirror).

Comment: Hi, thanks. If I create a new subdomain from the control panel (Plesk), what I need to do then? Change the root of the subdomain to match the folder on the main domain?

Comment: No, once you make the subdomain (and you already have the physical directory created) you should be good to go, but depending on your host set up you can double check if there are additional changes needed. Both should work: sub.domain.com and domain.com/sub

Comment: I've made a new subdomain, but the physical folder is outside the htdocs folder. So I have a sub.example.com folder for subdomain and an htdocs folder for main domain. What I don't know is how can I point the subdomain to the 'sub' folder in htdocs.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize - in this case you can just redirect. Do you have a link to this folder?

Comment: I can't put here the link to the folder. The problem is 'how' to redirect. The folder contains php files and some js files. I wish that pages like example.com/sub/page.php will be accessed like sub.example.com/page.php without having physical contents in the subdomain.

Comment: Just make a standard htaccess redirect - but it almost sounds like your files are 'outside' of the website main directory. So, in htaccess it would be something like this:                                           # This allows you to redirect index.html to a specific subfolder
 Redirect /subfolder/index.html http://whatever-your-link.is/

Comment: Like this:         RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^subfolder/index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/your-target-folder" [R=301,L]